# A non-negative integer base 3

Tags: radix, automata, computation-theory

I am actually having problem in understanding what does this actually mean :  "a non-negative integer base 3"

In In theory of computations, when we program something to check the membership of a WORD in a LANGUAGE. We do certain checks. 
But in this case I am not even getting what does this mean.
 **" {w ϵ Σ* | w is a non-negative integer base 3}"**

I've done research on Wikipedia but didn't get the concept. Hope that someone will make me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers of base 3 are integers formed using only the digits 0, 1, 2, like how binary numbers are integers of base 2.  The numbers from one to ten in base three would be

```
1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100, 101
```

Comment: Thanks. It was much easier than i thought it would be!